# Vmware commands executing batch file

Tags: batch-file, vmware, vmware-workstation

```
net use x: "\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\ShareME">>logfile.txt 2>&1
ping -n 11 127.0.0.1 > nul
x:
cd "Firefox18"
call autorun.bat>>logfile.txt 
cd ../
exit
```

When I execute the above batch file by double clicking, logfile.txt is generated. But when I use `vmrun -T ws -gu <Username> -gp <Password> runProgramInGuest <Vm-Path> <path of Batch File to execute>` The scripts runs fine, only the logfile.txt is not generated. 
This happens only in windows 7. It works fine for Windows XP.

Comment: It may still be getting generated, just not in the folder you are expecting.  The logfile.txt will be created in the working directory of the calling command interpreter. What is the working directory when you call the vmrun command?

Comment: One solution would be to explicitly declare where you want the log file to be written to.  Like this `>>"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\logfile.txt"`

Comment: @david post your comment as answer

Comment: I am working on the desktop. My bath file is placed on the desktop. I give the path of the desktop folder in 'vmrun'. I have tried using giving the full path name as you mentioned >>"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\logfile.txt" but that didn't worked. :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved I just needed >>"C:\Users\Ebryx 2\Desktop\logfile.txt" 2>&1 
The quotation mark for the path seemed to work for  windows 7.